# SetProperty / GetProperty on a mailItem does not work as expected when executed on Citrix

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, citrix

I have an Outlook VSTO plugin.

I use `mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) and `mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty) in order to save and retrieve some information regarding mail items. and it's working just fine.

However, when **(and only when)** executed on a Citrix environment, `SetProperty` does not throw any error, and `GetProperty` act as if no property existed. So I don't have any error.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: So GetProperty always throws an exception?

Comment: `GetProperty` throws an exception as if `SetProperty` was not used (default behaviour is to throw if not set, and to catch in order to treat is as default)

Comment: Can you actually see the property in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm - click IMessage button)?

Comment: Also, did you remember to call MailItem.Save after calling SetProperty?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to save the mail item (as it will save it as a Draft). On every other environments (that does not use Citrix), it's working fine. I saw somewhere that it might be because of the use of Exchange Cached Mode, not sure it's used yet. I will dig into this trail.

Comment: Well, if you don;'t save the item, the property won't persist.do you call GetProperty and SetProperty on the same object? Or do you reopen it?

Comment: I call it on the same object. But once again, it's working fine on every other environment. Also, we juste had confirmation, Exchange Cache Mode is recommended to be turned off on Citrix envs.
Do you know any other way other than Get/SetProperty in order to "attach" some info (Strings / Boolean) to a mailtem that should not require saving ? This property does not need to persist on the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is only for your internal purposes and it never needs to be saved, do not set the property - that can cause undesirable effects: the item becomes dirty, you waste a property mapping (you can have at most 0xFFFF named properties per mailbox - once you reach the limit, the mailbox is pretty much dead).

Create a wrapper class that holds `MailItem` object as a property as well as a list or a dictionary or a set of explicit properties to hold your temporary per-item data.

Comment: It seems over-complicated, because this Wrapper class should handle the MailItem lifecycle (creation and deletion) in order not to have memory leak. And more than that, even though I don't need "cold saving" of those properties, I'm not 100% sure MailItem reference does not change uppon usage (what if the user isolate the windows, or any other use case users always find...)

Comment: And regarding the 0xFFFF (65536) limit, I thnink we are really far from that :-)

Comment: I managed to solve this issue using a solution inspired by your, using a static `ConditionalWeakTable<Outlook.MailItem, Dictionary<String, object>> mailItemsProperties` containing all my properties. The `ConditionalWeakTable` managing through weak reference the mailItems lifecycle. Thanks !